# Use parseval's identity to prove $\int_0^\infty {\sin^4t \over t^2} dt = {\pi \over 4}$

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, parsevals-identity

I know how to calculate

$$\int_0^\infty {\sin^4t \over t^4} dt$$

by taking the function $f(x)=1-|x|$ and it will be $\pi \over 3$.

But here the denominator is not raised to power $4$ but $2$.
How should I approach it?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the method and the example you can solve?

Comment: The answer should be $\pi/4$

Comment: I have checked with Mathematica, it is $\pi/4$ @DavidG.Stork

Comment: As did I.   (The issue centered over which exponent in the denominator you had been referring to.)

Comment: Yes, I think the author asks for the $t^2$ case in the denominator. @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @MathFail yes im sorry it should be $\pi/4$

Comment: @YuriyS we fill find FT of f(x) in that case and use parsevals identity of equating squares of f(x) and F(s)

Comment: @AnshulBishnoi: I will reiterate Yuriy S's request for elaboration on the example you can solve. This will provide context and allow people to give more detailed answers. You might also read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x) := \begin{cases}-\frac14 & \text{if $0 \le x \le 2$}\\ \frac14 & \text{if $-2 \le x < 0$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$

\begin{align}
F\left(\omega\right) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}\mathrm d x\\
&= -\frac14\int_{0}^2 e^{-i\omega x}\mathrm d x + \frac14\int_{-2}^0 e^{-i\omega x}\mathrm d x\\
&= \frac1{4i\omega}\left(e^{2i\omega} - 1 - 1 + e^{-2i\omega}\right)\\
&= \frac1{i\omega}\left(\frac{e^{i\omega} - e^{-i\omega}}{2i}\right)^2\\
&= i\times\frac{1}{\omega}\sin^2\left(\omega\right)
\end{align}

By parceval identity:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^\infty \frac1{\omega^2}\sin^4\left(\omega\right)\mathrm d \omega
&= \frac1{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|F(\omega)\right|^2 \mathrm d \omega\\
&= \frac1{2} \times 2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f(x)\right|^2\mathrm d x\\ &= \pi \int_{-2}^{2}\frac1{16}\mathrm d x = \frac\pi{16} \times 4 = \frac\pi 4
\end{align}

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508) and [What is a PSQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854).

Comment: @robjohn I have read the two posts, but I haven't understood what should I do after that?

Comment: The idea is not to answer questions that are nothing more that problem statements and encourage the OP to improve the question. This question has not come under review, but if it does, it will probably be closed and possibly deleted.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your explanation. I will make sure to do that my next answers.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
I&=-\frac{\sin^4(t)}{t}|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty \frac{4\sin^3(t)\cos(t)}{t}~dt\\
\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(1-\cos(2t)\right)\cdot\sin(2t)}{t}~dt\\
\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2t)-\frac{1}2\sin(4t)}{t}~dt\\
\\
&=\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi}4=\frac{\pi}{4}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks but the question states that we have to use parsevals identity so can you suggest a function whose FT would be appropriate for this.

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508) and [What is a PSQ?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854).